# Extending Int to implement interface in c#

Tags: c#

Is it possible in C# (and I think it's not) to extend `int` to implement an interface (without creating a wrapper class)?

I have an interface like so

```
public interface IActionLoggerObject
{
    string GetForLogging();
}
```

I would like to (conceptually) be able to do this:

```
public class int:IActionLoggerObject
{
    string IActionLoggerObject.GetForLogging() { return "s"; }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is it possible (and i think it is not) to (in c#) extend "int" to implement an interface (without creating a wrapper class)?

No. You can never change which interfaces an existing type implements.

It's not clear why you're trying to do so, but creating a wrapper class is almost certainly the way forward here.

Comment: Jon is, of course, correct. But what are you trying to do here? Could you just use an extension method on Int?

Comment: I have a method for logging, and one of the parameters was of type IActionLoggerObject.  In my usage of this logging method I sometimes needed to pass an Int (or string) but it had to be of type IActionLoggerObject, so I have a wrapper object for them.  But I was just getting annoyed with doing that and was looking for a way of extending Int to implement the interface so that I wouldn't need that wrapper class.

Comment: @XenoPuTtSs: Can't you just overload the method?

Answer (score 4):

As MNGwinn mentioned in his comment on Jon Skeet's answer, you could use Extension Methods if they meet all of your requirements.

So, something like this:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static string GetForLogging(this int @this)
    {
        return "s"; // or maybe return @this.ToString();
    }
}
```

Would let you do this.

```
string val = 3.GetForLogging();
```

Answer (score 0):

Another extension method possibility:

```
public interface IActionLoggerObject
{
    string GetForLogging();
}

public class ActionLoggerObjectInt : IActionLoggerObject
{
    public string GetForLogging()
    {
        return "s";
    }
}

public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static IActionLoggerObject AsActionLoggerObject(this int i)
    {
        return new ActionLoggerObjectInt();
    }
}
```

usage:

```
Console.WriteLine(32.AsActionLoggerObject().GetForLogging());
LoggingMethod(32.AsActionLoggerObject());
```